# PHP_SELF and DOCUMENT_ROOT differs depending on browser

Tags: php, google-chrome, server, webserver

Today I stumbled upon a very strange thing.
The supervariable $_SERVER content depends on the browser.

I called exactly the same request on Chrome and Firefox and just output the $_SERVER variable in var_dump.

For whatever reason the DOCUMENT_ROOT isn't the same and respectively the PHP_SELF also differ.

**Chrome 80 & Opera 64:**

```
["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=>
  string(15) "C:/xampp/htdocs"
["SCRIPT_NAME"]=>
  string(23) "/dev/project123/root.php"
["PHP_SELF"]=>
  string(23) "/dev/project123/root.php"
```

**Firefox 70 & Internet Explorer 11 & Edge:**

```
["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=>
  string(15) "C:/xampp/htdocs/dev/project123"
["SCRIPT_NAME"]=>
  string(23) "/root.php"
["PHP_SELF"]=>
  string(23) "/root.php"
```

Does anybody know, why and how I can fix this issue? Is this a server-issue?

Thanks

Comment: how does a client dictate the server? O.o

Comment: very weird, isn't it? Same URL, same Server, same Script, but different Output :S

Comment: I'm *not* seeing this behaviour on my dev box - I've got the same output for those values in Chrome, Opera, Firefox (and Developer Edition) and Edge/IE11 ... as expected; are you literally just doing `var_dump($_SERVER)` on a test script? Nothing else? The changes in `DOCUMENT_ROOT` *really* look like different `<VirtualHost>` directives...

Comment: A browser alone could not result in differences like that. It has to be something on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. 
"http://localhost" is different depending on the browser. I don't yet know, why this can happen.

The .htaccess Rule to pass everything through a single php file ends with different DOCUMENT_ROOT-values.

So this is now an other issue.
Thanks. :)